# Mapping a sequence of results from Slick monadic join to Json

Tags: json, playframework, slick, playframework-2.4, slick-3.0

I'm using Play 2.4 with Slick 3.1.x, specifically the [Slick-Play plugin v1.1.1](https://github.com/playframework/play-slick). Firstly, some context...  I have the following search/filter method in a DAO, which joins together 4 models:

```
  def search(
              departureCity: Option[String],
              arrivalCity: Option[String],
              departureDate: Option[Date]
            ) = {
    val monadicJoin = for {
      sf <- slickScheduledFlights.filter(a =>
              departureDate.map(d => a.date === d).getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true))
            )
      fl <- slickFlights if sf.flightId === fl.id
      al <- slickAirlines if fl.airlineId === al.id
      da <- slickAirports.filter(a =>
              fl.departureAirportId === a.id &&
              departureCity.map(c => a.cityCode === c).getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true))
            )
      aa <- slickAirports.filter(a =>
              fl.arrivalAirportId === a.id &&
              arrivalCity.map(c => a.cityCode === c).getOrElse(slick.lifted.LiteralColumn(true))
            )
    } yield (fl, sf, al, da, aa)

    db.run(monadicJoin.result)
  }
```

The output from this is a Vector containing sequences, e.g:

```
Vector(
  (
    Flight(Some(1),123,216,2013,3,1455,2540,3,905,500,1150),
    ScheduledFlight(Some(1),1,2016-04-13,90,10),
    Airline(Some(216),BA,BAW,British Airways,United Kingdom),
    Airport(Some(2013),LHR,Heathrow,LON,...),
    Airport(Some(2540),JFK,John F Kennedy Intl,NYC...)
  ), 
  (
    etc ...
  )
)
```

I'm currently rendering the JSON in the controller by calling .toJson on a Map and inserting this Vector (the `results` param below), like so:

```
 flightService.search(departureCity, arrivalCity, departureDate).map(results => {
     Ok(
        Map[String, Any](
          "status" -> "OK",
          "data" -> results
        ).toJson
     ).as("application/json")
 })
```

While this sort of works, it produces [output in an unusual format](https://gist.github.com/rossanthony/e9fa5382cdb68610f373cce5e0007c7f); an array of results (the rows) within each result object the joins are nested inside objects with keys: "_1", "_2" and so on.

So the question is: How should I go about restructuring this?

There doesn't appear to be anything which specifically covers this sort of scenario in the Slick docs. Therefore I would be grateful for some input on what might be the best way to refactor this Vector of Seq's, with a view to renaming each of the joins or even flattening it out and only keeping certain fields?

Is this best done in the DAO search method before it's returned (by mapping it somehow?) or in the controller after I get back the Future results Vector from the search method?

Or I'm wondering whether it would be preferable to abstract this sort of mutation out somewhere else entirely, using a [transformer](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJsonTransformers) perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [JSON Reads/Writes/Format Combinators](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Writes)

In the first place you must have `Writes[T]` for all your classes (`Flight`, `ScheduledFlight`, `Airline`, `Airport`). 
Simple way is using Json macros

```
implicit val flightWrites: Writes[Flight] = Json.writes[Flight]
implicit val scheduledFlightWrites: Writes[ScheduledFlight] = Json.writes[ScheduledFlight]
implicit val airlineWrites: Writes[Airline] = Json.writes[Airline]
implicit val airportWrites: Writes[Airport] = Json.writes[Airport]
```

You must implement `OWrites[(Flight, ScheduledFlight, Airline, Airport, Airport)]` for Vector item also. For example:

```
val itemWrites: OWrites[(Flight, ScheduledFlight, Airline, Airport, Airport)] = (
  (__ \ "flight").write[Flight] and
  (__ \ "scheduledFlight").write[ScheduledFlight] and
  (__ \ "airline").write[Airline] and
  (__ \ "airport1").write[Airport] and
  (__ \ "airport2").write[Airport]
).tupled
```

for writing whole `Vector` as `JsAray` use `Writes.seq[T]`

```
val resultWrites: Writes[Seq[(Flight, ScheduledFlight, Airline, Airport, Airport)]] = Writes.seq(itemWrites)
```

We have all to response your data

```
flightService.search(departureCity, arrivalCity, departureDate).map(results => 
  Ok(
    Json.obj(
      "status" -> "Ok", 
      "data" -> resultWrites.writes(results)
    )
 )
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed response. I have `Writes[T]` in place already for all of the classes using Json macros, it's just the Vector that's returned from the join query that I wasn't sure how to handle. Currently the search method in the DAO is just returning a generic Vector containing the sequence of objects as mentioned. Do I need to define a new object to act as a carrier for the result Vector, inside which I add the resultWrites val of type `Writes.seq[T]`? Otherwise where should this go?

Comment: Ok, got it working, by adding what you suggested above the call to `flightService.search` in the controller. I'm not convinced this is the correct place though, I guess the `val itemWrites: OWrites...` and `val resultWrites: Writes...` could be mixed in via a trait. It doesn't feel right to have it in the controller, but equally it doesn't really make sense to define a pseudo model object to hold the result sequence. Anyway, thanks again for your guidance with this, it's been a big help.

Comment: You can define your pseudo model, but you must implement own Writes then. `Writes.tupled` is just writer for such pseudo model implemented by `Tuple`. Your writes are simple, more complex I try move outside controllers actions only for testing. You may move this Writes in companion object (if controller is implemented as class) for one time initialization.